# Shortcut for evaluating strings in data.table assignments

Tags: r, data.table, eval

Wrangling data with `data.table`'s, I find myself writing lines like this third line a lot:

```
DT = data.table(a = 1:10)
name = 'a'
DT[,eval(parse(text=sprintf('%s_plus_one := %s + 1',name,name)))]
```

which I had hoped to reduce to

```
DT[,s('%s_plus_one := %s + 1',name,name)]
```

using a function like:

```
# s is *very* short for substitute and evalute
s <- function(...)
    eval(parse(text=sprintf(...)))
```

but then I get this error:

```
> DT[,s('%s_plus_one := %s + 1',name,name)]
    Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").
```

I know I can do this:

```
# sp is short for substitute and parse
sp <- function(...)
    parse(text=sprintf(...))

DT[,eval(sp('%s_plus_one := %s + 1',name,name))]
DT
#>      a a_plus_one
#>  1:  1          2
#>  2:  2          3
#>  3:  3          4
#>  4:  4          5
```

but building strings to be evaluated in a data.table assignment is so common, that I'd hoped minimize typing as much as possible.

Comment: why not build call from language objects instead of parsing string? it gives kind of validation before it is being evaluated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much of the time there shouldn't even be a need to go into the world of `eval(parse())`. I.e., for this example, put the name in parentheses on the left-hand side and use `get` on the right-hand side:

```
DT[, (paste0(name,"_plus_one")) := get(name) + 1]

DT
#     a a_plus_one
# 1:  1          2
# 2:  2          3
# 3:  3          4
# 4:  4          5
# 5:  5          6
# 6:  6          7
# 7:  7          8
# 8:  8          9
# 9:  9         10
#10: 10         11
```

Comment: I didn't try, but I'm pretty sure the parentheses are not needed on lhs

Comment: @eddi - in this case, yep, but I tend to do it out of reflex as `DT[, (name) := get(name) + 1]` and `DT[, name := get(name) + 1]` give different results.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `.SDcols`

```
DT[,(paste0(name,"_plus_one")) := .SD+1, .SDcols=name]
DT
#     a a_plus_one
# 1:  1          2
# 2:  2          3
# 3:  3          4
# 4:  4          5
# 5:  5          6
# 6:  6          7
# 7:  7          8
# 8:  8          9
# 9:  9         10
#10: 10         11
```

As @thelatemail mentioned this would also work with multiple columns

```
DT = data.table(a = 1:10, b=2:11)
name <- c("a","b")
DT[,(paste0(name,"_plus_one")) := .SD + 1, .SDcols=name]
```

Comment: Bonus question: is there a way to use this solution when merging two data.tables which contain variables of the same name, as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36367293)?

Comment: @Jthorpe Perhaps you may check `.EACHI` .  Without an example, it is not clear how you want to do it.