# Update join: replace with values from a column with the same name

Tags: r, join, data.table

I need to merge some data from one `data.table` into another. I know how to add a new column from one `data.table` to another in a join. Below values from column `b` in `df2` is added to `df1` in a join based on the `Id` column:

```
df1 <- data.table(Id = letters[1:5], a = 1:5)
df2 <- data.table(Id = letters[1:3], a = 7:9, b = 7:9)
setkey(df1, Id)
setkey(df2, Id)
df1[df2, b := b][]
#>    Id a  b
#> 1:  a 1  7
#> 2:  b 2  8
#> 3:  c 3  9
#> 4:  d 4 NA
#> 5:  e 5 NA
```

However, that idiom does not work when the column already exists in `df1`, here column `a`:

```
df1[df2, a := a][]
#>    Id a
#> 1:  a 1
#> 2:  b 2
#> 3:  c 3
#> 4:  d 4
#> 5:  e 5
```

I understand that `a` is not updated by this assignment because the field `a` already exists in `df1`. The reference to `a` in the right hand side of the assignment resolves to that value, not the on in `df2`.

So how to update values in `df1$a` with those in `df2$a` in a join on matching `id` to get the following:

```
#>    Id a
#> 1:  a 7
#> 2:  b 8
#> 3:  c 9
#> 4:  d 4
#> 5:  e 5
```

Comment: use `j = a := i.a`

Comment: Thanks! I knew there had to be a simple solution!  Just to be clear for others, the `j=` is naming the argument to `[.data.table`, as in `df1[df2,a:=i.a]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `?data.table`:

> When `i` is a data.table, the columns of `i` can be referred to in `j` by using the prefix `i.`, e.g., `X[Y, .(val, i.val)]`. Here `val` refers to `X`'s column and `i.val` `Y`'s.

Thus, in the RHS of `:=`, use the `i.` prefix to refer to the `a` column in `df2`, `i.a`:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(Id = letters[1:5], a = 1:5)
df2 <- data.table(Id = letters[1:3], a = 7:9, b = 7:9)
setkey(df1, Id)
setkey(df2, Id)
df1[df2, a := i.a]

# or instead of setting keys, use `on` argument:
df1[df2, on = .(Id), a := i.a]

df1
#        Id     a
#    <char> <int>
# 1:      a     7
# 2:      b     8
# 3:      c     9
# 4:      d     4
# 5:      e     5
```